# Confused about proof with rational/irrational numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

I'd like to solve this simple task but I am stuck:

> Prove the following statement by proving its contrapositive: if $r$ is irrational, then $r^{1/5}$ is irrational.

I think the contrapositive would be: If $r^{1/5}$ is rational, then $r$ is rational. But I am confused. Doesn't $r^{1/5}$ always turn into the $5$<sup>th</sup> root of $r$ which makes the result always irrational?

Comment: Hint: $r = (r^{1/5})^5$ so if $r^{1/5}$ is rational then...

Comment: No.  Fifth roots are not always irrational.  For example, the fifth root of $32$ is rational.  And besides, if it were true that fifth roots are always irrational, there would still be the question of how to prove that.

Answer (score 2):

No, $r^{1/5}$ isn't automatically irrational. Just look at $r = 32$. Then $r^{1/5} = 2$.

And yes, your contrapositive is correctly stated. Your proof should start something like this:

> Suppose that $r^{1/5}$ is rational, so  $r^{1/5} = \frac{a}{b}$ for some integers $a$ and $b$. But then $r = \cdots $

Answer (score 0):

$$ r\notin\Bbb Q\Rightarrow\sqrt[5]r\notin\Bbb Q\iff\sqrt[5]r\in\Bbb Q\Rightarrow r\in\Bbb Q$$

$$\sqrt[5]r\in\Bbb Q\iff \sqrt[5]r=\frac ab \text{ where } a,b\in\Bbb Z, b\ne 0$$
This implies
$$r=\frac{a^5}{b^5}$$ where $a^5$ and $b^5$ satisfy the same conditions that $a$ and $b$, which means that $r$ is rational.